# Use 301 Redirection Code But Finding 302 from Header Checker Tool

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, http-status-code-301, http-status-code-302

Right now I am using SSL for 3 Sits and Config that on website. Using Apache server from `Godaddy`.

I have redirect `http://` to `https://` from `Htaccess`.
Using 301 redirection code and that are:

```
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.your domain name.com/$1 [R,L]
```

But finding this redirection as 302 from Header tool as well screaming frog.

Is there any right solutions for that?

Comment: Have you tried replacing  `R` flag with `R=301` ?

Comment: By default, apache R flag does a temperory Redirect using 302 status code, use R=301 to make it permanent.

Comment: Thanks for the Help..Its working now